# Когда нужно вызывать GetExitCodeProcess

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Функцию `GetExitCodeProcess` нужно вызывать до, или после `CloseHandle`?

```
if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\schtasks.exe", ptr, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    DWORD lp;
    if (GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, (&lp)))
        qDebug() << parseError(&lp);
    else
        qDebug() << "ошибка EXITA";
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(&si);
}
else
    qDebug() << GetLastError();
```

Comment: Конечно до. После вам выдаст ошибку Invalid hanlde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После `CloseHandle` хэндл становится невалидным и с ним уже никакую функцию вызывать не надо.

Comment: Ну я так и думал, просто небольшая ошибка, которую я не мог определить, навела меня на такую мысль